# How can you export images from an .emd file with hyperspy?

Tags: python

Given a HAADF-STEM Spectrum Image (SI) as .emd (Velox) file, I want to extract all individual HAADF-images from the stack.

I assume there is an easy way with hyperspy, but I am unable to identify it.

My code so far:

```
import hyperspy.api as hs
path = r'C:\Users\SI_File.emd'
s = hs.load(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following, the code can be simpler but I included variables to minimise retyping filenames.

In order, the process is:

-import file

-split stack into individual images

-iterate save for all images (my stack was 30 images, hence i<=29) into a new
folder and save as ripple format.
http://hyperspy.org/hyperspy-doc/current/user_guide/io.html#id38

Install the ripple-to-dm4 script to digital micrograph and batch convert the ripple files to .dm4.
http://hyperspy.org/hyperspy-doc/current/user_guide/io.html#import-rpl

```
%matplotlib qt
import hyperspy.api as hs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f="FILENAME"
s = hs.load(f'{f}.emd')

s_haadf = s[1].split()

i = 0
while i<=29:
    s_haadf[i].save(f'{f}/{f}_{i:03d}.rpl')
    i+=1
```